# Python AssertionError

Tags: python

When I check the ISBN(DIGIT) with my code : check_digit_13(2000003294107)

```
def check_digit_13(isbn):
    assert len(isbn) == 12
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(isbn)):
        c = int(isbn[i])
        if i % 2: w = 3
        else: w = 1
        sum += w * c
    r = 10 - (sum % 10)
    if r == 10: return '0'
    else: return str(r)
```

The Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser.py", line 16, in <module>
    lk.run(document)
  File "/data/www/crons/lk/parser.py", line 33, in run
    field = lkmapper.all(row, document)
  File "/data/www/crons/mappers/lk.py", line 5, in all
    print isbn.check_digit_13(field[0])
  File "/data/www/crons/libs/isbn.py", line 13, in check_digit_13
    assert len(isbn) == 12
AssertionError
```

Comment: You cannot possibly be calling that function with `check_digit_13(2000003294107)` because that is an integer; the exception would be different (a `TypeError` would be thrown). You'll have to debug what `field[0]` is and find out why there are fewer or more than 12 characters in that.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

- Stop.
- Think.
- What is the interpreter trying to tell you?
- Assertion error?
- Which assertion?
- There is only one in your code.
- The traceback even shows you which one.

Check the input to your function. Is it a string? Then count the characters. How many? 12? I counted 13.

Comment: I feel like this should be a classic answer. It applies (with minimal modification) to about 50% of questions, being of the form "I got this exception which tells me what's wrong and where, how do I fix it?"

Comment: Thanks for your help - for me the main point was "Stop. Think."

Answer (score 6):

`assert len(isbn) == 12` should be `assert len(isbn) == 13`. After all, current ISBN codes are 13 digits long, and so is your example input. Maybe you got confused because indexes start at 0, but length is length, so it's 13.